# Kotlin-JS interop - using language constructs

Tags: kotlin

I have a js interop function which is using the `for in` construct to iterate over the input elements, but it's throwing error at runtime.

```kotlin
native("document")
val ndoc: dynamic = noImpl

fun jsInterOp() {
    js("console.log('JS inling from kotlin')")

    val ies = ndoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
    for (e in ies) {
      console.log("Input element ID: ${e.id}")
    } 
}
```

Getting the following js error

```
Uncaught TypeError: r.iterator is not a functionKotlin.defineRootPackage.kotlin.Kotlin.definePackage.js.Kotlin.definePackage.iterator_s8jyvl$ @ kotlin.js:2538
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this one?

Kotlin : M12

The generated js code for the function is,

```kotlin
    jsInterOp: function () {
      var tmp$0;
      console.log('JS inling from kotlin');
      var ies = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
      tmp$0 = Kotlin.modules['stdlib'].kotlin.js.iterator_s8jyvl$(ies);
      while (tmp$0.hasNext()) {
        var e = tmp$0.next();
        console.log('Input element ID: ' + e.id);
      }
    },
```

Comment: Could you show the corresponding peace of the generated JS?

Answer (score 3):

`forEach` didn't work because it's an `Array` function in JS, but `getElementsByTagName` returns [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) . So i changed the kotlin code to use the traditional for loop which iterate over this collection and is work as expected.

```kotlin
 val ies = ndoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
 for (i in 0..(ies.length as Int) - 1) {
    console.log("InputElement-${i} : ${ies[i].id}")
 }
```

Comment: Note that Kotlin's `for in` is not the same as JavaScript's `for in` and they have the different semantic.

Comment: @bashor could you please provide more details or any doc explaining how it's semantically different in JS ?

Comment: And about JS [for-in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin for-loop uses a lot of internal magic.`forEach()` is more straightforward on JS. Try this:

```
ies.iterator().forEach { ... }
```

It seems to be a bug in Kotlin M12, because I was unable to do a for-loop even on simple a list.

```
for(i in listOf(1, 2));  // TranslationInternalException
```

**Also**

I am not sure what is that `document` that you use here, but you may like the standard API:

```
import kotlin.browser.document
val ies = document.getElementsByTagName("input")
```

Comment: Thanks!  `native("document")`  is used just to learn how js interop works in kotlin.

Comment: `ies.iterator().forEach { ... }` doesn't work, getting the same error
`Uncaught TypeError: r.iterator is not a function` . More over, now it's giving a warning message to use sequence() function instead of iterator().